# Apparent link between the zeta function and $\ln(10)$

Tags: zeta-functions

Why does $$\sum_{i=10^x}^{10^{(x+1)}-1} \frac{1}{i}$$ seem to tend towards $\ln(10)$ as $x $ increases?

Comment: Trusting that $r=i$, compare your sum to the related definite integral.

Comment: You could try and use the fact that $H_n = \ln n + \gamma + o(1)$ as $n\to\infty$, where $H_n := \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$ and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{i=10^x}^{10^{(x+1)}-1} \frac{1}{i}=H_{10^{x+1}-1}-H_{10^x-1}=\log10^{x+1}-\log10^x+o(1)=\log10+o(1)$$ where $H_n$ denotes the n-th harmonic number